# How to get Result data from android native calculator

Tags: android, calculator

I'm invoking android native calculator from my app, how do i get result data from it.. means i started native calender like this, after finishing calculation i press back onActivityResult is not executing.. Help me

```
 Intent i = new Intent();
 i.setClassName("com.android.calculator2",
                "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
 startActivityForResult(i, 1); 

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == 1){
        Log.i("CALCULATOR", "Result Data is"+ data);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start it:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.android.calculator2",
"com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
```

Then the Calculator Acitivity should use
`setResult(RESULT_SUCESS, simple_intent_with_result_as_extra)`

When the Calculator Activity Exits, the onActivityResult will be called on your original Activity with that Intent you passed earlier.

Comment: Sir i'm using Native calculator, how do i write setResult(RESULT_SUCESS, simple_intent_with_result_as_extra) inside native code..