# Invoke Android's calculator on an app and get its values?

Tags: android, return, native, calculator

I am doing a project where I gotta open up the phone's calculator. It's working alright. The thing now is: how can I get the data from that application? Is it possible?

For instance, the user typed 2+2 and then pressed the "equals" button. I need to get those values (the equation, 2+2, and the result, 4) and store in my project. How could I possibly do it? I've been searching everywhere but couldn't find a solution for this so far.

Thanks in advance!

Ps:. Here are the links I've found on my research so far:

[How retrieve values from the Android Calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239942/how-retrieve-values-from-the-android-calculator)

[Get Back Result from Android native Calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578192/get-back-result-from-android-native-calculator)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553893/how-to-get-result-data-from-android-native-calculator

Comment: as it wasn't answered there here is a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578192/get-back-result-from-android-native-calculator

Comment: The answer is not clear enough on those links, gentleman. :(

Comment: I think they are, no, you cannot, that app doesn't set a result for your 'startActivityForResult' call. You can't even be sure if this app would be installed (manufacturers can install their own calculator app). As suggested in @SebastianWalla link, you can write your own calculator activity.

Comment: @GuillermoMerino is right. Because the native calculator is open source, as it is mentioned somewhere on the linked sites, you can easily write your own calculator.

Comment: So it is impossible to do it? The only way out is writing my own calculator?